# What is the common behavior for partial edits using JSON with an API?

Tags: rest, api

I have an API and I've exposed an `EditUser` Endpoint that accepts JSON data with optional values. Our UI allows clearing text a field and saving to clear the field (as opposed to a clear button) and saves the data as null.

From an API perspective, what's the common behavior for having different input for "Edit", "clear", or "leave as is".
Suppose we have some information we'd like to edit that looks like the following:

```
   {
    nickname: "foo"
    firstName: "John"
    lastName: "Doe"
   }
```

Given someone "cleared" the lastName field and hit save, our UI would send an input:

```
   editInput = {
    nickname: "foo"
    firstName: null
    lastName: "Doe"
   }
```

So the JSON input passed is all the other fields along with the new field. (We use google datastore which doesn't allow for partial updates).

Given that, exposing this API we do not expect someone adding edits to know the current state every time, and may want to send an edit input as follows
`input = { nickname: "bar" }` with firstName and lastName `undefined`. If they would like to clear the fields, they'd pass

```
   input = {
    nickname: "foo"
    firstName: null
    lastName: null
   }
```

Is this standard or is the default passing `""` (or `{}`, `[]` if clearing non-string fields)? How would boolean fields be cleared in this way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard, so defer to the principle of least surprise.

It would be reasonable to expect the following to clear `firstName` and `lastName` and set `nickname` to "foo"

```
{
  nickname: "foo"
  firstName: null
  lastName: null
}
```

It would be reasonable to expect the following to set `nickname` to "foo" and leave `firstName` and `lastName` as is

```
{
  nickname: "foo"
}
```

However `PUT` is *supposed* to be for complete updates, so you may want to use `PATCH` instead.